# Glass RenderLink not rendering right media url

Tags: glass-mapper, link-manager, renderfield, razor

Sitecore verison - 9.0.2
Glass version - 5.0.6.0

We are trying to use Glass @RenderLink to render a pdf media item, it's generating anchor tag with below path

> /sitecore/media-library/site-content/xxx/your-account/xxx/xxx/pdfFileName

Which is going to page not found as expected. I believe it should render as below:

> /~/media/site-content/xxx/your-account/xxx/xxx/pdfFileName.ashx

Looks like Glass issue, am I right?

Is there an alternative way to render pdf link, our cshtml is a Glass View rendering.

*Code Example view.cshtml:*

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<xxx.Data.GlassModel.sitecore.templates.xx.Journeys.Components.Ixxx>

@Editable(x=>x.Heading)
@RenderLink(x=>x.LinkName)
@Editable(x=>x.Description)
```

Glass model is generated by TDS and the Link field in the model as below:

```
[SitecoreField(Ixxxx.LinkNameFieldName)]
Link LinkName{get; set;}
```

Comment: Can you add a code example of how you are rendering the link? And how your model is setup?

Comment: What type of field is your `LinkName` field?

Comment: @DanSinclair GeneralLink

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri how did you select your media item? Did you use a `Media Link` or an `Internal Link`? I've sometimes found one to be problematic when creating links, where the other works fine (can't remember which is which off the top of my head).

Comment: @DanSinclair I used media link.

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri did you try using an `Internal Link` (linking to the same media item) to see if the URL was generated properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative for rendering pdf link media item through Glass.

```
@Editable(x=>x.LinkName)
```

worked for me.